# notification of editing done in uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I have some labels in a custom UITableViewCell but heres the thing they are in a line, but when editing begins all of the labels jumble together. I have two of the labels have an autoresizing margin and it works if all of the labels have less then the actual bounds of the text label. So I tried some things, and thought I could take the width of the first text label down when editing begins by having tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath move the width, but then I am never notified if the editing is finished (user hits done button) and then can't move the width back and then the text label gets all screwy and all of these labels getting jumbled. I would just like to know the best way in order for me to not have the labels get jumbled (auto shrink/autoresize) and then have them revert to their original position.

Thanks in advance, if needed I will upload some code to see what I have done so far

Comment: first off, the user is not editing labels they're editing UITextFields...

Comment: No that would be editing a uitableviewcell I'm talking about a uitableview with deleting and moving rows in the table view